# How to read a file path from database column and display the contents using angular

Tags: angular, filepath, display

I have a requirement to  read a file path from a database column and display the contents in a  popup using Angular. The files can be of type  image, pdf , video etc. The files path will have filenames that can be accessed remotely /locally.

Comment: Welcome, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better results.

Comment: Angular should never have direct access to database (unless you use IndexedDB). You need API for that.

Comment: I do have an API to handle that part. I need to know how to access the file content after getting fetching the path name .The file could be image / text/ pdf etc